# Button drawable background

Tags: android, xml, button, drawable

I want to change the button background using a drawable. The problem I have is that the button did not chang properly.

**Gradient button.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:endColor="@color/primaryYellow"
        android:startColor="@color/primaryGreen"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners android:radius="20dp" />

</shape>
```

**Button I'm applying the drawable:**

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_button"
            android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_italic"
            android:text="@string/all"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/darkNeutral"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnFavorites"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I tried to apply `android:backgroundTint` property with the same drawable which lead to a build error.

Comment: You need to define "Did not change properly".  What didn't change, what did you expect and what did you get?  Also please note that buttons work in Android by setting a background.  So if you overwrite the background like that without using a state list drawable with pressed states, there will be no press animation

Comment: The button changed only the shape but not the gradient color I defined in main_gradient.xml file.

In fact, it is the default one that comes from the theme.